# Running same function for different arguments in a loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, function, arguments

I have large 3D same-sized array of data like density, temperature, pressure, entropy, … . I want to run a same function (like divergence()) for each of these arrays. The easy way is as follows:

```
div_density = divergence(density)
div_temperature = divergence(temperature)
div_pressure = divergence(pressure)
div_entropy = divergence(entropy)
```

Considering the fact that I have several arrays (about 100), I'd like to use a loop as follows:

```
var_list = ['density', 'temperature', 'pressure', 'entropy']
div = np.zeros((len(var_list)))
for counter, variable in enumerate(var_list):
    div[Counter] = divergence(STV(variable))
```

I'm looking for a function like STV() which simply changes "string" to the "variable name". Is there a function like that in python? If yes, what is that function (by using such function, data should not be removed from the variable)?
These 3D arrays are large and because of the RAM limitation cannot be saved in another list like:

```
main_data=[density, temperature, pressure, entropy]
```

So I cannot have a loop on main_data.

Comment: side note: please name your variables lower case.. `Main_data` that hurts ;)

Comment: regarding your ram issue: how do you load the data? if you read them from different files and loop over them anyways, why not load the data in the loop so always just one of the arrays is loaded..

Comment: I should not change the variables' names as lots of calculations are completed with these names. If I use a new list like main_data, all previous names should be changed (like density to main_data[0], temperature to main_data[1], etc.) and may hurt several parts of the code. Also we have RAM limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to use `exec` as follows

```
var_list = ['density', 'temperature', 'pressure', 'entropy']
div = np.zeros((len(var_list)))
for counter, variable in enumerate(var_list):
    s = "div[counter] = divergence("+variable+")"
    exec(s)
```

`exec` basically executes the string given as the argument in the python interpreter.

Comment: you have to be sure that the strings are valid variable names and not executable code/functions. You have the risk of code injection if you read the strings from some where else. So IMHO this is the correct answer to the question, but probably not a good solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

how about using a dictionary? that links the variable content to names.
Instead of using variable names `density = ...` use dict entries `data['density']` for the data:

```py
data = {} 
# load ur variables like:
data['density'] = ...

divs = {}
for key, val in data.items():
   divs[key] = divergence(val)
```

Since the data you use is large and the operations you try to do are computational expensive I would have a look at some of the libraries that provide methods to handle such data structures. Some of them also use c/c++ bindings for the expensive calculations (such as numpy does). Just to name some: numpy, pandas, xarray, iris (especially for earth data)

Comment: Variables are loaded previously and lots of calculations are completed. Now the divergence() function should be run for all of them. The main question is that is there a function which changes "string" to the "name of an existing variable"?

Comment: the short answer is: yes, you can use exec() as @Sankar answered, but this is not a very elegant way. I would still use dictionaries which fit perfect for this job ;)

Comment: edited my answer for data which is already loaded..